differences in httr vs httr2 output
Lets consider two ways to make a call to API - via httr and httr2 as suggested by @ismirsehregal and @ifeanyi-idiaye in this topic
library(httr)
library(httr2)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

# httr
resp<- GET("http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/Dataflow") %>%   
  content(as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8") %>% 
  fromJSON()

imf_datasets1 <- resp$Structure$Dataflows$Dataflow

# httr2
req <- request("http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/Dataflow")
resp1 <- req |> req_perform()
parsed_body <- resp_body_json(resp1)

imf_datasets2 <- parsed_body$Structure$Dataflows$Dataflow %>% as.data.frame()

Both calls refer to the same endpoint, but the two output dataframes (imf_datasets1 and imf_datasets2) have different shape. The one retrieved via hhtr+jsonlite has much nicer format, even though I haven't done any manipulation there. It means that it was done "in the background" (probably) by jsonlite package. Why resp_body_json can't do it? Can I get the same nice df like imf_datasets1 using httr2?

Did you already try passing simplifyVector = TRUE?

httr2::resp_body_json() is basically a jsonlite::fromJSON() wrapper, but uses different default for simplifyVector  . You can pass any fromJSON argument to resp_body_json to make it behave as you prefer.

@KonradRudolph - thanks a lot. simplifyVector = TRUE indeed helped a lot

@margusl thanks, I wasn't aware that resp_body_json() and fromJSON() are essentialy the same
